# Changing a program to be able to install directly after downloading

Tags: file, installation, zip, download

So I have a program I am letting people download on my site currently. The problem is when they receive the download it saves as a zip folder to a destination on their machine. They then have to navigate to the folder, extract the contents, and then run the correct .exe to start the installation. How can I convert this process so that they can simply open the program and start the installation without having them navigate to the folder and unzip it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not let them download EXE ? The EXE file can be self-extracting (eg. WinZip can make self-extracting EXE archives which will unpack contents and run the predefined extracted file (such as main EXE of your application).